# Why BFS stuck in Graph Node representation?

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

I have created graph using Node and Edge class.

When I call `traverseBFS` method from `start = 0`. then It just stuck. cannot proceed further. When I use similar approach with `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>` this algorithm runs properly. Please help me how to fix this.

> Complete Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Dijkstra {
    static class Node {
        public int id;
        public long dist;
        public int par;

        public Node(int a, long d, int b) {
            id = a;
            dist = d;
            par = b;
        }
    }

    static class Edge {
        int to;
        int weight;

        public Edge(int a, int b) {
            to = a;
            weight = b;
        }
    }

    static int vert;
    static ArrayList<LinkedList<Edge>> list;
    static int[] parent;
    static long[] distance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        vert = sc.nextInt();
        int edges = sc.nextInt();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        parent = new int[vert + 1];
        distance = new long[vert + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= vert; i++) {
            list.add(i, new LinkedList<Edge>());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {
            int u = sc.nextInt();
            int v = sc.nextInt();
            int w = sc.nextInt();
            list.get(u).add(new Edge(v, w));
            list.get(v).add(new Edge(u, w));
        }
        traverseBFS(0);
    }
    public static void traverseBFS(int start) {
        System.out.print("\nBFS >> \n");
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[vert];
        LinkedList<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(start);
        visited[start] = true;

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int s = q.poll();
            System.out.print(s + " ");

            LinkedList<Edge> temp = list.get(s);
            for (Edge var : temp) {
                if (!visited[var.to]) {
                    visited[var.to] = true;
                    q.add(var.to);

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Input

5 6

1 2 2

2 5 5

2 3 4

1 4 1

4 3 3

3 5 1

> Output

BFS >>

0

Comment: see the second pseuodcode on [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breitensuche#Algorithmus) wiki-page (sorry that it is the german site, but I think it is the better example)

Comment: to the question of representation: There are many ways to represent a graph and which one should be choosen depends on the task at hand. But there are three well known options Adjacency-Matrix, Adjacency-List (discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/)) and Edge-List (this then is just a list or set of the edges together with just a set of nodes (necessary because a node can have no neighbors))

Comment: Can you post enough code here for us to reproduce the error on our end? As in, could you show off the code that you used to create the graph and run BFS?

Comment: Please post [mre]. Include test data.

Comment: Please post mre and not  a link to the full code. Hard code the test data.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're saying

Comment: [copy the code into the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also add the test case as hard-coded data, not as an image.  You're asking us to volunteer to solve your problem, 
 and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so. (Tip: add @c0der to the message so I get notified)

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) consider hard coding test data, to make it easier to run a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] neighbours = {

            {1,2,2},

            {2,5,5},

            {2,3,4},

            {1,4,1},

            {4,3,3},

            {3,5,1}
    };

    vert = 5;

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    parent = new int[vert + 1];
    distance = new long[vert + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= vert; i++) {
        list.add(i, new LinkedList<Edge>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.length; i++) {
        int u = neighbours[i][0];
        int v = neighbours[i][1];
        int w = neighbours[i][2];
        list.get(u).add(new Edge(v, w));
        list.get(v).add(new Edge(u, w));
    }

    traverseBFS(0);
}
```

A simple print out the graph created shows that node 0 is not connected to any other node:

> Node 0 connected: []
>  
>   Node 1 connected: [to 2, to 4]
>  
>   Node 2 connected: [to 1, to 5, to 3]
>  
>   Node 3 connected: [to 2, to 4, to 5]
>  
>   Node 4 connected: [to 1, to 3]
>  
>   Node 5 connected: [to 2, to 3]

---

To simplify the printout add `toString` method to Edge:

```
static class Edge {
    int to;
    int weight;

    public Edge(int a, int b) {
        to = a;
        weight = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "to "+to;
    }
}
```

and use

```
  for(int node = 0; node < list.size(); node ++){
     System.out.println("Node "+node +" connected: " + list.get(node));
  }
```